# What level of canon is the lore in Star Wars: The Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars, video-games, canon

I was wondering: there is a lot of lore in Star Wars: The Old Republic, and some events could be seen as contradictions. What level of canon is given to this game?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Pre-Disney:**

All games are ***C-canon*** (other than those explicitly excluded, like *Star Wars Galaxies*)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Expanded_Universe#Official_levels_of_canon

**Post-Disney:**

As per [Pablo Hidalgo on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/818601288329900032), it's ***EU/Legends***

> Yeah SWTOR is a continuation of our Legends/SWEU storytelling
>   *3:32 PM - 9 Jan 2017*

Answer (score 4):

> - G (George Lucas) canon is absolute canon. This category includes the
>   final releases of the six films, the novelizations of the films, the
>   radio dramas based on the films, the film scripts, and any material
>   found in any other source (published or not) that comes directly from
>   George Lucas himself. G canon outranks all other forms of canon.
> - T (Television) canon, which currently comprises Star Wars: The Clone
>   Wars and the as yet unaired live action Star Wars TV series. This
>   level of canon is considered to take precedence over C canon (see
>   below), possibly due to the fact that George Lucas is directly
>   involved with these shows as executive producer, and in the case of
>   The Clone Wars is also on the writing team.
> - C (continuity) canon refers to the main body of EU work, and is the next most authoritative
>   level of canon. All material published under the Star Wars label that
>   doesn't fall into either G, T, S, or N canon is C canon and is
>   considered authoritative as long as it isn't contradicted by G canon.
> - S (secondary) canon refers to older, less accurate, or less coherent
>   EU works, which would not ordinarily fit in the main continuity of G
>   and C canon. For example, this includes the popular online roleplaying
>   game Star Wars Galaxies, and certain elements of a few N-canon
>   stories.
> - N continuity material is also known as "non-canon" or
>   "non-continuity" material. What-if stories (such as those published
>   under the Infinities label) and anything else that cannot at all fit
>   into continuity is placed into this category. "N-continuity" is not
>   considered canon.

[Shamelessly stealing DVK's Link as source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Expanded_Universe#Official_levels_of_canon)

I am pretty sure the TOR would fall into the S category because it mixes elements of C cannon (Persistant in world Major NPC's and lore) with elements of non cannon - Basically all PC Actions, exchanges, and generic NPCs.

Comment: I think it's more nuanced - the game itself is "C" and the conflicting elements (non-canon PC actions) are non-canon (or S) without affecting the entire game. This was the deal with KOTR if I recall correctly

Comment: @DVK TOR is mmorpg like Galaxies rather than KotOR(Knghts of the Old Republic(a linear rpg action game)) which i would agree would be C... now to find some more acronyms i can drop :p

Comment: I agree with DVK, I would think there's a C-canon version of the quests/events in SWTOR, and all other possibilities given to the player are N-canon.

Comment: @MatthewRead - It is more complicated than that.  The story behind the quest is C-Canon but once you get into doing the quest it becomes non-canon when the player characters get involved.  There are probably elements of C canon mixed in where NPC's take scripted actions.

Comment: That's exactly what I intended to say :P

Answer (score 0):

Certain elements of Player involvement are C-canon; Scripted or Linear outcomes are to be considered C-canon.

*Minor Spoilers Below*

Example: all interactions with Revan have singular outcomes, in itself confirming the C-canon status of Revan before, during and directly after SW:TOR, The C-Canon PC involvement in the Maelstrom could be interpreted as 1. Jedi Knight, 1. Smuggler, 1 Jedi Consular and 1. Trooper, The Identity, Advanced Class and Alignment all being S-canon so the player can have their own version of events in "official" canon.